# AutoHotKey issue with AltTab shortcut

Tags: autohotkey

i was trying to create a simple script with AHK to switch between windows (similar to the "recent" button on a samsung mobile) with this code:

```
XButton2::
Send, {Alt down}{Tab}
Return
```

the problem is that i don't know how to make the script to release the Alt key when i strike Enter or click the Left mouse button.
Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
XButton2:: 
    AltTabMenu := true  ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to this variable
    Send, {Alt down}{Tab}
return

; The #If directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys:

#If (AltTabMenu) ; If this variable has the value "true" 

    ; The * prefix fires the hotkey even if extra modifiers (in this case Alt) are being held down

    *Enter::
    *MButton::
        Send {Enter}
        Send {Blind}{Alt Up} ; release Alt
        MouseCenterInActiveWindow()
        AltTabMenu := false
    return

    ~*LButton::
        Click
        Send {Blind}{Alt Up} ; release Alt
        MouseCenterInActiveWindow()
        AltTabMenu := false
    return      

    ; menu navigation by scrolling the mouse wheel:

    *WheelUp:: Send {Right} 
    *WheelDown:: Send {Left}

#If ; turn off context sensitivity

MouseCenterInActiveWindow(){
    WinGetPos,,Y, Width, Height, A ; get active window size
    Xcenter := Width/2        ; calculate center of active window
    Ycenter := Height/2 
    MouseMove, Xcenter, Ycenter, 0
}
```

Comment: thank you @user3419297 BUT .. when i have more than 2 open windows and i try to switch to other than the previous window (3rd, 4th and so on) by clicking on it with the left mouse button, it doesn't switch to that window. it just switches to the 2nd one like if i am simply pressing Alt & Tab one time.
i liked the idea of using the mouse wheel to choose between open windows but i'd like to be able to select the window by just clicking
is there any way around this?

Comment: What OS are you on (Win7, Win10)?

Comment: I am on Windows 10

Comment: I didn't understand what the last edit was for? Can you explain it please?

Comment: It automatically moves the mouse pointer to the center of the activated window.

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote the script for AutoHotkey v2:

```
XButton2::
{
    ErrorLevel := !KeyWait("XButton2", "T0.3")
    if (ErrorLevel)
    {
        Send("{Alt down}{Tab}{Alt up}")
        ErrorLevel := !KeyWait("XButton2")
    }
    else
    {
        Send("{Alt down}{tab}")
    }
}

; https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabRemarks
#HotIf  WinExist("ahk_class XamlExplorerHostIslandWindow")  ; Indicates that the alt-tab menu is present on the screen.
    ~*LButton::  ; The * prefix allows it to fire whether or not Alt is held down.
    {
        Click()
        Send("{Alt up}")
    }
    *Enter::
    *MButton::
    {
        Send("{Enter}")
        Send("{Alt up}")
    }
    ~*Esc::Send("{Alt up}")  ; When the menu is cancelled, release the Alt key automatically.
    ;*Esc::Send "{Esc}{Alt up}"  ; Without tilde (~), Escape would need to be sent.
#HotIf
```