# AutoHotKey: make Win+Tab act as Alt+Tab, but remap all other Win+ combinations as Ctrl+

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to make my MacBook in Windows behave similar to macOS: so I can switch between apps using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (i.e., replicate the Alt+Tab action), but have all the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>...</kbd> actions (like, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, etc) be accessible using the Win key (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).

In other words, I am trying to :

1. Remap <kbd>Win</kbd> key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in all key combinations, but also
2. Have the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> act exactly as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and I don't care if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> stops
   working as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, because I am not using that key combination at
   all).

I am able to separately individually achieve 1. using `LWin::Ctrl`, and 2. using `LWin & Tab::AltTab`, but I cannot make them work together. Whenever I have something like

```
LWin::Ctrl
LWin & Tab::AltTab
```

or

```
LWin::Ctrl
Ctrl & Tab::AltTab
```

it just stops working, I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the symbols like documented [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)?

For your snippet that would mean:

```
LWin::Ctrl
LWin & Tab::Send, !{Tab}
```

There is a problem with this, as it simulates closed keystokes (regard `!{Tab}` as `{Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}`. If you want to press and hold <kbd>Win</kbd> and then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or eventually tab multiple times), this doesn't work. To adress this issue, I found three main workarounds:

1. )

Let <kbd>Alt</kbd> stick to being pressed down:

```
LWin::Ctrl
LWin & Tab::Send, {Alt Down}{Tab}
LWin & Capslock::Send, {Alt Up} ;Suppose you won't use that hotkey elsewhere
```

2. )

Use something [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35971730/4575793) by [2501](http://2501):

```
h::AltTabMenu  ; Opens the menu. Press second time to close.
n::AltTab      ; Alt-Tabs through forwards
m::ShiftAltTab ; Alt-Tabs through backwards
```

The underlying principles/functionalities are documented [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabDetail).

3. ) Dig into AHK really deep: [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm) (which is referenced in [1](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols))

<sub>**Annotation:** Be aware that</sub>

```
<#::Ctrl
<#Tab::!Tab
```

<sup>does not work as Windows then handles the <kbd>win</kbd> key on its own first. You can verify This by testing:</sup>

```cpp
<#::
MsgBox test
return
<#Tab::
MsgBox test
return
```