# Alt-Tab on shortcut with meh-key in AHK v2

Tags: autohotkey

I want to map meh+i onto alt+tab in windows. (The meh-key is the combination alt+shift+ctrl).

Is this possible with Autohotkey v2?

Remarks:

- As I understand [the documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#alttab), this is not possible using the `AltTab` action, as only 2-key-combinations can be mapped onto that action. Correct me if I'm wrong.
- This means, I need to build this the old way, simulating key presses and waiting for keys to be lifted, is that correct?

  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35971452/2302262) old thread, and I've adapted it to what I assume is the correct syntax for v2:

  ```
  #!^i:: {
    Send "{ALT DOWN}{TAB}" ; If i is down it invokes the menu for switching windows.
    KeyWait "i" ; Show menu for switching windows by keeping ALT down until user physically releases i.
    Send "{ALT UP}" ; If i is released release ALT key
  }
  return
  ```

  However, this only works for "one press"; repeated presses of `i` do not move the selected window further.

I assume I have to build-in some loop that waits for a repeated press of the `i` key, and that drops out of the loop as soon as any of the modifiers is released.

(Why want to do this remapping at all? I use meh+key for window management operations: move a window around, move focus to another window, move to another desktop, etc. Alt-tab belongs in that group, so I want to have the same "prefix" as the other operations.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meh-key is the combination Left Control + Shift + Alt.
Try this:

```
; #HotIf GetKeyState("Shift") and GetKeyState("Alt") ; redundant

    LCtrl & i::AltTab

; #HotIf ; redundant
```

**EDIT:**

**[Alt-Tab Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/Hotkeys.htm#AltTabRemarks)** says

> **Alt-tab actions are not affected by #HotIf.**

that is

```
LCtrl & i::AltTab
```

can work in this case without the #HotIf directive.

My apologies for misleading you.

**EDIT 2:**

If your keyboard layout has a left Control key, and you don't want  AltTab to be fired on both `left Control + i` and `meh-key + i`, try this:

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
    
; LCtrl+Alt+Shift+i  = meh-key+i  = AltTab

<^+!i:: {
  Send "{Alt Down}{Tab}"
  AltTabMenu := true  ; assign the Boolean value "true" or "1" to the variable "AltTabMenu"
}

; The #HotIf directive creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstings:

#HotIf (AltTabMenu := true) ; If this variable has the value "true"
    
    ~*LCtrl Up::
    ~*Alt Up::
    ~*Shift Up::
    {
        Send "{Alt Up}"
        AltTabMenu := false 
    }

#HotIf  ; turn off context sensitivity
```

Comment: Please, see EDIT in this answer.

Comment: Hmm. But wouldn't that already fire on ctrl + i? Instead of alt+shift+ctrl i?

Comment: If your keyboard layout has a left Control key, it will fire on both `left Control + i` and `meh-key + i`. Otherwise only on `meh-key + i`.

Comment: See also EDIT 2 in this answer.